# The fb access token always get expired in ember app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ember.js, ember-cli, facebook-sdk-4.0, ember-addon

I am using ember-simple-auth and ember-cli-facebook-js-sdk.I am using the ember-cli-facebook-sdk because I want to get the user photo anytime as facebook only give the access which expires in 60 mins.So I can't save also.Ember-cli-facebook-sdk is working fine.But sometimes I am getting an error in my network console.

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException"}
```

I am not able to think why this error is coming.I have a initializer which have facebook id and api version.And Now I am using Fb.api and others in my controller,component and other.But it fails sometimes.Please anwser where I am going wrong.Thanks in advance.

initializer/fb.js

```
import FB from 'ember-cli-facebook-js-sdk/fb';

export default {
  name: 'fb',
  initialize: function() {
    return FB.init({
      appId: '1234567',
      version: 'v2.3',
      xfbml: true
    });
  }
};
```

controller.js

```
usrphoto:Ember.computed('model',function(){
          var currentState = this;
          FB.api('/me/picture','Get',{'type':'large'}).then(function(response) {
            currentState.set('usrphoto', response.data.url)
            })
      }
```

Comment: @Hillboy I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happens here is, that your Facebook session expires. In that case you need to handle the error and manage it. For example, you could check for a valid session and in case the session is expired, require a new token and then do your request:

```
FB.getLoginStatus().then(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    return Ember.RSVP.resolve();
  } else {
    return FB.login('email,user_photos'); //set your scope as needed here
  }
}).then(function() {
  return FB.api('/me/picture','Get',{'type':'large'});
}).then(function(response) {
  currentState.set('usrphoto', response.data.url);
});
```

Another possibility is to handle the error in the catch of the FB.api:

```
FB.api('/me/picture','Get',{'type':'large'}).then(function(response) {
  currentStatte.set('userphoto', response.data.url);
}).catch(function(reason) {
  ...handle your error here...
});
```

Comment: but for login I am using ember-simple-auth addon

Comment: When I check for loginStatus and If it fails and return fb.login.Will it open a new dialog box for fb permission

Comment: @MarutiNandan if the user have already accepted the App permissions, then no dialog will appear (well, actually, it will open and close very quickly)